Subtracting pandas series from all elements of another pandas series with a common ID
I have a pandas series.groupby objects, call it data. If I print out the elements, it looks like this:
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at ***>
(1, 0     397.44
    1     12.72
    2     422.40
Name: value, dtype: float64)
(2, 3     398.88
    4     6.48
    5     413.52
Name: value, dtype: float64)
(3, 6     398.40
    7     68.40
    8     18.96
    9     56.64
    10    406.56
Name: value, dtype: float64)
(4, 11    398.64
    12    14.64
    13    413.76
Name: value, dtype: float64)
...

I want to make an equivalent object, where the entries are the cumulative sum of each sublist in the series, minus the first entry of that list. So, for example, the first element would become:
(1, 0     0         #(= 397.44 - 397.44)
    1     12.72     #(= 397.44 + 12.72 - 397.44)
    2     435.12    #(= 397.44 + 12.72 + 422.40 - 397.44)

I can get the cumulative sum easily enough using apply:
cumulative_sums = data.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
but when I try to subtract the first element of the list in what I would think of as the intuitive way (lambda x: x.cumsum()-x[0]) , I get a KeyError. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Try:
cumulative_sums = data.apply(lambda x: x.cumsum() - x.iat[0])
print(cumulative_sums)

Prints:
a  b 
1  0       0.00
   1      12.72
   2     435.12
2  3       0.00
   4       6.48
   5     420.00
3  6       0.00
   7      68.40
   8      87.36
   9     144.00
   10    550.56
Name: value, dtype: float64


Beautiful, thank you.

The best would be to avoid apply (which is a loop) and to use cumsum/transform that are optimized for this specific task:
cumulative_sums = data.cumsum()-data.transform('first')

Output:
0       0.00
1      12.72
2     435.12
3       0.00
4       6.48
5     420.00
6       0.00
7      68.40
8      87.36
9     144.00
10    550.56
11      0.00
12     14.64
13    428.40
Name: value, dtype: float64

The gain in speed is quite remarkable:

Note that, if the values are sorted by group in the original dataset, you can even avoid the groupby. Assuming df the input with group/value as columns:
cs = df['value'].cumsum()
cumulative_sums = cs-cs.mask(df['group'].duplicated()).ffill()

Variant with two Series:
cs = series.cumsum()
cumulative_sums = cs-cs.mask(group.duplicated()).ffill()

Which is even faster:

Example input for the alternative:
series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 10, 2, 30, 7, 1, 2, 3])
group = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': group, 'value': series})


Impressive speed-up! This is a one-off to optimization isn't so important here for me, but this is a great answer for anyone attempting something similar and I will keep this in mind for future related tasks.
